# Creating custom abstract environment

Tags: environments, koma-script, abstract, kaobook

I would appreciate any help in creating a custom abstract environment in `kaobook` document class (it is based on `koma-script`). Here is what I have done so far

```
\newenvironment{secabstract}[1]{%
\hrule
\small\textbf{\abstractname: } 
\small\emph #1 
}{%
\newline\hrule
\vspace{0.6cm}
}
```

The problem is that I cannot set the text in italics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the `kaobook` class but below I used `scrbook` which you said was the basis for `kaobook`. The following revises your `secabstract` environment to set text in italics.

```
% abstractprob.tex  SE 571787
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\providecommand{\abstractname}{Abstract} % not in scrbook class
\newenvironment{secabstract}[1]{%
\hrule
\small\textbf{\abstractname: } 
%\small\emph #1     %  emph takes an argument
\small\emph{#1} % or \small\textit{#1} 
\itshape % use this if you want the text to be in italics
}{%
\newline\hrule
\vspace{0.6cm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{secabstract}{An abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{secabstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick, very useful. But... how could I add this abstract to the TOC?

Comment: You should ask this as a new question. However, put `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{An abstract}` after the start of the `secabstract` environment.